# Incorrect input shape after loading Keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm successfully loading a model from a file, and when I try to predict output on any input with shape (480,) I'm getting ValueError as follows:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_1 is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 480 but received input with shape (32, 1)

The code that I'm using

```
import numpy as np
from keras.models import load_model

model = load_model("my_model.h5")
sample = np.zeros((480,))
model.predict(sample)
```

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

My model summary after loading:

[image]

Training of this model looks reasonable, but if I'm trying to predict values just after invoking model.compile() the same error happens.

```
    model = keras.models.Sequential([
        keras.layers.Input(shape=(480,)),
        keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
        keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
        keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer3"),
        keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer4"),
        keras.layers.Dense(38, activation="softmax", name="output")
    ])
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0003), 
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        metrics=['categorical_accuracy']
   )
   
   sample = np.zeros((480,))
   model.predict(sample)  # ValueError
   model.fit(...)  # works fine
```

Comment: How many neurons are there in your input layer of the model? Can you provide your model specification first?

Comment: @strikersps I've just updated my question. I'm using keras.layers.Input with shape parameter (480,)

Comment: Does it work if you don't save it first? So you create the model compile, and then try to predict? If not, can you post that minimal example so that we can debug as well?

Comment: @J369 I've tested it and the same ValueError is raised when trying to predict straight after invoking model.compile(). The training loop seems valid as the results are reasonable. It should not matter since I've been doing this multiple times and never encountered such issues but I'm running this on Deepnote (similar to Google Colab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me instead; I added "1" to the shape of the input sample:

```
import numpy as np

model = keras.models.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Input(shape=(480,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer1"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer2"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer3"),
    keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation="relu", name="layer4"),
    keras.layers.Dense(38, activation="softmax", name="output")
])
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0003),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',
    metrics=['categorical_accuracy']
)

sample = np.zeros((1, 480,))
model.predict(sample)  # No ValueError
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I don't think I'd figure it out swiftly...

Comment: Yeah I'm looking in the docs for this behavior and haven't found it...

Comment: Model expects batch dimension; `np.zeros((1, 480,))` will return a shape (1,480) instead of (480,) where 1 is interpreted as batch dimension.

Comment: @Frightera in that case, why do we get (32, 1) without it? Is that some default? I.e. what is the behavior when we don't give batch; I would think it should throw a clearer error.

Comment: That's most likely default value of batch size which is 32.